# Change the order of nodes in a single-linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Say we have a list 1-2-3-4-5 (values of list can be without order, for example 2-4-5-3-1);
The task is to reorder nodes of list (not values) in the way like this:
1-5-2-4-3.
I wrote the function that uses 2 temporary variables and 1 pointer. But the problem is I don't know how to set the "next" pointer in penultimate node to "NULL" without defining the second temporary pointer in function.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
void Swap(Node* begin)
{
    if (begin->next != NULL || begin->next->next != NULL)
    {
        Node temp1 = *begin; //this variable is used for iteration
        Node* temp2 = begin; //pointer to the target node
        Node prev; //get the adress of last node
        while (temp1.next != NULL)
        {
            prev = temp1;
            temp1 = *temp1.next;
        }
        prev.next->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = prev.next;
        Swap(prev.next->next);
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? what pattern does the order "1-5-2-4-3" represents?

Comment: It represents the order of nodes. Last node should be after the first, penultimate node after the second, etc

Comment: So, `Swap` is a recursive function.

Comment: Obtaining a specified order is usually the same as *sorting*. To sort a linked list you can use merge sort. This assumes that you have some way of determining whether two nodes are in order or not.

Comment: But actually there's no way to determine it except going through the one side of list to another. That's exactly what I do. After sorting 2 elements function recursively sorts the smaller list.

Comment: This way you are seeking to the end of the list every single recursion.

Comment: @ThunderWiring what does that have to do with anything ?

Comment: The algorithm implies that list can be of any any size.

Comment: @Alexei Unless it's a specific requirement or exercise I wouldn't get bogged down in how many temporary variables you create. In almost all circumstances really makes the most piffling difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this algorithm: o(n) time complexity

1. Count the no of nodes(n) in list.
2. Put the last n/2 nodes in a stack.
3. Start traversing the list from the starting.
4. For each traversed element, pop the element from stack and make it the next element of the traversed element.
5. Do this until stack gets empty.
6. Keep in mind to change the last node next pointer to NULL.

   (In case of odd count you have to traverse one more element even if stack is empty)

Answer (score 0):

so basically What you want to do is this :

```
N0, N1, ..., Nm -> N0, Nm, N1, Nm-1, ..., Nm/2   if m is even
                -> N0, Nm, N1, Nm-1, ..., N(m-1/2), N(m+1/2)
```

you can maybe walk your list from  `i in (m/2 +1)..m` (in reverse) (assuming m is even) remove the node and insert it in the `i+1`'th place

or walk your list from  `i in (m/2 +1)..m` (assuming m is even) remove the node and insert it in the `m-i+1`'th place